# How do I configure Visual Studio to launch Chrome with --remote-debugging-port=9222 when debugging a service?

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-debugging

I want Visual Studio to launch Chrome with the command line parameter `--remote-debugging-port=9222` when debugging my web application.  This would enable me to connect to that browser from Visual Studio Code (which I know how to do).

How can I configure the command line parameters Visual Studio uses when launching a browser while debugging?

Comment: Maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Scenarios) gives you some help.`chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`?

Comment: Thanks, but that document doesn't really address this issue.  Microsoft actually just released a VS2019 update that addresses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 v16.2 addresses this issue.  There is now a Browse With option in the IIS Express dropdown that allows you to configure launch parameters.

See [Microsoft Edge Insider Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#microsoft-edge-insider-support) - This actually supports all browsers.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the document not helps and thanks for your sharing. You can consider marking it as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for checking in on this.  The new VS feature is super helpful in many debugging scenarios.